# Embedded Microsoft Word 2016 in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, excel, winapi, ms-word

I'm need to have embedded Microsoft Word 2016 in Windows Forms.

I have tried it with (Setparent), but it did not work with Word. [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/85d0972f-9655-48fc-ac5d-0ac7f9acc8b7/problem-with-setparent-api-in-excel-2013?forum=winforms)

```
Excel.Application excApp = new Excel.Application();
excApp.Visible = true;
hwnd1 = (IntPtr)excApp.Hwnd;
SetParent(hwnd1, tabPage2.Handle);
MoveWindow(hwnd1, 0, 0, tabControl1.Width, tabControl1.Height, true);
excApp.Workbooks.Add();


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nheight, bool repaint);
```

I have tried various components, like Telerik, Devexpress, and Dotnetbar.

But I'll want use Microsoft Word.

Comment: `SetParent`'ing windows from a different process is not supported and will never work reliably.  You need to rethink your approach, its hard to think of any justification for doing what your attempting.  If you want to interact with Word uses its COM object model, you can do this from C# or within Word itself.

Comment: @AlexK.: *Technically*, it is supported ([Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)), iff you control both applications at the API level. The OP doesn't control either. so it won't work reliable for them.